# How to read output from a subprocess but dont get blocked for new lines

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a subprocess inside my python code and I want to communicate with it on demand. the subprocess won't finish upon calling and will stay open. so I want to call a function and read the stdout lines from the subprocess until that moment, in other words, I don't want the program to wait for new inputs. this is my code:

```py
print("Starting Stockfish Engine...")
engine = subprocess.Popen(
    'stockfish',
    universal_newlines=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    bufsize=1,
)


def send_command(command):
    print('\nyou:\n\t' + command)
    engine.stdin.write(command + '\n')


def get_result():
    line = engine.stdout.readline()
    while engine.stdout.readable():
        print(line)
        line = engine.stdout.readline()


get_result()
send_command("uci")
get_result()
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into sending an EOF or the equivalent of CTRL-C to the subprocess's standard input? I'm not certain either would work but I figure it's worth trying. You haven't indicated that you've looked into anything so I have no idea if you've already tried that or not.

Comment: I don't want to close the subprocess and rerun it every time. i want it to be open and read from output whenever i need to. sending SIGINT will close the subprocess.